# How the high performance and low latency of Apache APISIX is achieved

Tags: nginx, lua, apache-apisix

How are the high performance and low latency of Apache APISIX derived? What is its technical implementation?

Comment: You can consult the source code directly to see the "technical implementation": https://github.com/apache/apisix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that APISIX leverages to achieve high performance and low latency. Such as:

#### 1. Using etcd as the configuration center.

It is a reliable data store that provides a watch mechanism, using this, APISIX becomes aware of the changes in near-realtime. Unlike other API Gateways that poll the database for updates.

#### 2. High-Performance Route Matching Algorithm

It uses a radix-tree based high performance route matching algorithm that also supports fuzzy matching.

#### 3. Hashtable-based IP matching algorithm.

Read [here](https://apisix.apache.org/blog/2022/09/13/why-is-apache-apisix-the-best-api-gateway/#high-performance-ip-matching-algorithm).